Chabad Maamar Avodah definition
What is the definition or description of "mamarei avodah" and how does this differ from any other maamar? This seems to be a Chabad specific term.

https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8#.D7.9E.D7.90.D7.9E.D7.A8.D7.99_.D7.A2.D7.91.D7.95.D7.93.D7.94_.D7.95.D7.94.D7.A9.D7.9B.D7.9C.D7.94

B"H
The term avoda'dikeh maamar" is a vernacular yeshiva-styke way of describing a maamar that focuses mainly on what one should do in life to overcome one's obstacles.
Even though the vast majority (all?) of Chabad Maamarim do this to an extent, the avoda'dikeh Maamarim have it as of a central focus, as opposed to just deeper analyses of things.
More on the subject of Maamarim:
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2905524/jewish/What-Is-a-Maamar.htm

Overcoming one's obstacles is a bit narrow. I would say it's chassidus made personal. For one person that may translate to overcoming obstacles, for another it could mean davening with more inspiration.
